# I am the only person with access to my machine. Any reasons to enable group/other permissions on files and directories?

Tags: permissions

I have noticed that some files in my home directory have read and write permissions for `group` and even `other`.

If I am the **only person** who I want to give access to my machine, is there any reason to enable `group` or `other` permissions for files or directories?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on the file or directory.

For example, some web server setups allow the machine's users to publish files as `http://server.name/~username`, with the files typically living in that user's subdirectory. `httpd` will probably need execute permissions on the directory containing the files and all of the directories above it in the path, due to the way it processes URLs. In other words, if you have `~username/public_html` set to 777, but `~username` is 700, Apache probably can't serve the files.

The broader answer to the question requires you to consider *all* the daemons running in the system. They typically do not run as either root or your user, so they do not automatically have permissions for any files in your directory unless given them explicitly.